# Swap Catalog Images for Product Thumbnails in Related Products on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the related.php woocommerce loop in wordpress so that the images that sit inside the related products div are the thumbnail variants and not the catalog images. I appreciate I can resize the catalog images using CSS but in order to prevent unnecessarily long load times etc I'd rather load the smaller thumbnail version instead. Is this possible?

It looks like I need to edit the following function in some way but I'm starting to struggle and want it to be update proof:

```
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Nobody have any suggestions?